# Get string enclosed in curly braces with escaping using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract text enclosed inside curly braces. But the complication is that any closing curly brace `}` with preceding back-slash `\` should be included as well in the result.

For example, for the string `{abc123*-\\}}`, I want to extract the text as `abc123*-\\}`.

Here is a code sample that I have achieved so far:

```js
var content = '{abc123*-\\}}{sdf}';
var regex = /\{(?<text>([^\}]|(?<=\\)\})*?)\}/;
var firstMatch = content.match(regex); // results 'abc123*-\\'
```

Comment: If my solution works for you, please consider accepting the answer. Else, please let know what is still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```js
var content = '{abc123*-\\}}{sdf}';
var regex = /\{([^\\{}]*(?:\\[^][^\\{}]*)*)}/;
var firstMatch = content.match(regex); // results 'abc123*-\\'
if (firstMatch) {
  console.log(firstMatch[1]);  // => abc123*-\}
}
```

**Details**

- `\{` - a  `{` char
- `([^\\{}]*(?:\\[^][^\\{}]*)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^\\{}]*` - 0+ chars other than `\`, `{` and `}`
  - `(?:\\[^][^\\{}]*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\\[^]` - any escaped char (a `\` followed with any char)
    - `[^\\{}]*` - 0+ chars other than `\`, `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nK2NV5/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%7B(%5B%5E%5C%5C%7B%7D%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C%5B%5E%5D%5B%5E%5C%5C%7B%7D%5D*)*)%7D):

[image]

Comment: Can `[^]` be replaced with `.` instead?

Comment: @Barun `.` only finds any char but line break chars. `[^]` or `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]` will find any char. Also, `.` with `s` flag in the latest ECMAStandard will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for deep nested curly braces,

Example 1,

```js
var content = '{abc123*-\\}}{sdf}';
var regex = /(?<=\{)(.*?)((?=(?=\}\}))(?=\}).(?!\}{2})|(?!(?=\}\}))(?=\}))/g;
var firstMatch = content.match(regex); 
console.log(firstMatch);
```

Example 2,

```js
var content = '{{{abc123*-\\}}}}{sdf}}}}}}';
var regex = /(?<=\{)(.*?)((?=(?=\}\}))(?=\}).(?!\}{2})|(?!(?=\}\}))(?=\}))/g;
var firstMatch = content.match(regex); 
console.log(firstMatch);
```

This will give you all groups of strings in between outer braces { } in a string.